# Java string to array handling

Tags: java, arrays

I have these data from two different files like these:

**file 1 :**

- 1001, Name One
- 1002, Name Two
- 1003, Name Three
- 1004, Name Four
- 1005, Name Five

**file 2:**

- 1001, 1234, 450
- 1002, 2345, 560
- 1003, 3456, 730
- 1004, 4567, 200
- 1005, 5678, 1000

as seen from the date above they have reference with each other *(1001, 1002, ... , 1005)*
my question what is the proper way to combine them into a single **array** and retrieve them via there references.

Comment: Write some code. If you encounter a problem, you can ask here ;)

Comment: yeah i'm trying it out, and still trying as of now :(

Comment: Is the first line correct with 2 on one line or is each pair on a new line?

Comment: @Skepi each is pair in every line

Comment: Read the file line by line, regex to split the line string by the ", " , and create a map like Kevin suggests below. Same reading technique for the second file and you can reference the Map to get the matching item values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could work with a [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)

```
Map<Integer,String>;
```

then you could store the first file, with all these id´s in an [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

In the second file you could simply look up the values and write both of them into the Map

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use a Map instead of an array.

Iterate over each row, and add an entry to a Map using the first one as Key (If the entry already exists simply add to the content).